# Storm Program not running

Tags: apache-storm

So I was trying to learn apache storm and was using the tutorialspoint guide as a reference point for working with my first storm program(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_storm/apache_storm_quick_guide.htm)

I do not get the call log count output as expected. My zookeeper however shuts down

My topology is:

```
public class logAnalyserStorm {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    Config config = new Config();
    config.setDebug(true);

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("call-log-reader-spout", new FakeCallLogGeneratorSpout(),100);

    builder.setBolt("call-log-creator-bolt", new callLogCreatorBolt()).shuffleGrouping("call-log-reader-spout");

    builder.setBolt("call-log-counter-bolt", new callLogCounterBolt()).fieldsGrouping("call-log-creator-bolt", new Fields("call"));

    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    cluster.submitTopology("logAnalyserStorm", config, builder.createTopology());

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    cluster.killTopology("logAnalyserStorm");

    cluster.shutdown();

}
```

}

The error is:

```
20680 [Thread-10] INFO  o.a.s.event - Event manager interrupted
20683 [main] INFO  o.a.s.testing - Shutting down in process zookeeper
20683 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory - NIOServerCnxn factory exited run method
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my nimbus was not running. Ugh. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Change Thread.sleep(10000); to Thread.sleep(60000);